# change image on hover and keep the text

Tags: html, wordpress, css

i am recently working with Wordpress and bootstrap .
i am trying to have 1 image on every colum containter , and change the image on Hover , but keep the text it was before on original image .. 
there is any way with CSS3 or i need to use JS for this ? 
Here is my HTML CODE :

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

      <div class="page-header">
      <h1 class="titletxt">ECO GREECE</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 imageHolder img1">
            <div class="overlay img1">
              <span class="plus"> walking </span>
              </div>
           </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 imageHolder img2">
        <div class="overlay img2">
              <span class="plus"> walking </span>
              </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 imageHolder img3">
        <div class="overlay img3">
              <span class="plus"> marine tour </span>
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 imageHolder img4">
        <div class="overlay img4">
              <span class="plus"> birds watching </span>
              </div>
        </div>
      </div>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

and here is the CSS :

```
.imageHolder {
    position: relative;
}
.imageHolder.img1 {
    background: url('http://localhost/eco-greece/wp-content/themes/ecotheme/img/bear.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 420px;
    background-position: center center;
}
.imageHolder.img2 {
    background: url('http://localhost/eco-greece/wp-content/themes/ecotheme/img/bridge.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 420px;
    background-position: center center;
}
.imageHolder.img3 {
    background: url('http://localhost/eco-greece/wp-content/themes/ecotheme/img/couple.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 420px;
    background-position: center center;
}
.imageHolder.img4 {
    background: url('http://localhost/eco-greece/wp-content/themes/ecotheme/img/bird.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 420px;
    background-position: center center;
}

.overlay {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    padding:180px 0 100px 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease;

}
.overlay.img1 {
    background: url('http://localhost/eco-greece/wp-content/themes/ecotheme/img/bear_over.png') no-repeat;
    height: 420px;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
.overlay.img2 {
    background: url('http://localhost/eco-greece/wp-content/themes/ecotheme/img/bridge_over.png') no-repeat;
    height: 420px;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
.overlay.img3 {
    background: url('http://localhost/eco-greece/wp-content/themes/ecotheme/img/couple_over.png') no-repeat;
    height: 420px;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
.overlay.img4 {
    background: url('http://localhost/eco-greece/wp-content/themes/ecotheme/img/bird_over.png') no-repeat;
    height: 420px;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
.imageHolder:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
}
.ec-imageText {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 1;
    padding:180px 0 100px 0;
}
.plus {
    position: relative;
    opacity: 1;
    font-family: myriadpro;
    color:rgba(255,255,255,.85);
    font-size: 45px;
}
```

With this code , image changes on hover and show some text , but i want the text on original image too ..

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly understand your question, but I'll give this a shot. Use the `:hover` selector and change the `url()` for `background-image`
I made a very simple [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/75v52hg4/) for you.

Comment: OK, i did in that way, but for some reason all worked , except transition .. and i dont know why

Comment: You can't apply opacity only to background-image. It will be applied to the whole `div`

Answer (score -1):

it would be really helpful to be able to run this bit of code independently to debug

```
placeholder to submit
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d7ohv42j/

i made a JSfiddle for you, but without external linking, i can't even begin to see what kind of errors you might be getting, especially if it's a display error

will check back